# Uploading image to a node via Angular to Drupal 8 using REST

Tags: 8, javascript

I have figured out how to upload files from Angular to Drupal 8

```
......
submitCommunity: function(params) {
  var package = {
    "_links":{"type":{"href":"http://dang.dev:8888/rest/type/file/file"}},
    "filename":[{"value":Math.round((Math.random()*1000)).toString() + '.jpg'}],
    "filemime":[{"value":"image/jpeg"}],
    "data":[{"value":params.bannerImage}] //params.bannerImage = B64 encoded string of the image
  };
  $http.post('http://dang.dev:8888/entity/file', package, config).then(function(response) {
    var fileId = response.headers().id; // the file ID of the newly created file entity.
  });
},
......
```

My question is, what if I have a content type that has an image field in it? Specifically, my content type is of type `community` and contains a field called `field_banner_image`. Below is what I have now, however, it produces `422 Unprocessable entity` with a response of:

`{"error":"Unprocessable Entity: validation failed. field_banner_image: This value should not be null."}`

`field_banner_image` is required hence the error, but I have no idea what `field_banner_image` expects me to send it.

```
.....
submitCommunity: function(params) {
  var package = {
    "_links":{"type":{"href":"http://dang.dev:8888/rest/type/file/file"}},
    "filename":[{"value":Math.round((Math.random()*1000)).toString() + '.jpg'}],
    "filemime":[{"value":"image/jpeg"}],
    "data":[{"value":params.bannerImage}] //params.bannerImage = B64 encoded string of the image
  };
  $http.post('http://dang.dev:8888/entity/file', package, config).then(function(response) {
    var fileId = response.headers().id;
    package = {
      _links: {'type':{'href':'http://dang.dev:8888/rest/type/node/community'}},
      type: [{'target_id': 'community'}],
      title: [{'value': params.title}],
      body: [{'value': params.body}],
      field_banner_image:[{'value': fileId}]
    }
    return $http.post('http://dang.dev:8888/entity/node?_format=hal_json', package, config);
  });
},
.....
```

I've tried `field_banner_image:[{'fid': fileId}]` and some other combos of key values, but I think I am attacking this wrong. Documentation on this is kind of sparse right now and a lot of it is old D8 beta stuff. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ImageItem](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!image!src!Plugin!Field!FieldType!ImageItem.php/class/ImageItem/8) and [FileItem](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!file!src!Plugin!Field!FieldType!FileItem.php/class/FileItem/8) are represented as entity references. The ImageItem has the following schema: `target_id`, `alt`, `title`, `width`, and `height`.

Only the `target_id` column is a required property, which can be seen through ImageItem::propertyDefinitions > FileItem::propertyDefinitions >  [FieldReferenceItem::propertyDefinitions](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Field!Plugin!Field!FieldType!EntityReferenceItem.php/function/EntityReferenceItem%3A%3ApropertyDefinitions/8) parent method.

The field should be represented similar to the `type` property, which also is an entity reference.

Comment: Funny, I had just figured this out and posted an answer right when you did. You sir can have the points! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Aha, I figured it out! I ended up finding the answer within views. One of my views was exporting the data as Fields. I switched it back to entity (default display when using rest) and I noticed `field_banner_image` had a list of fields associated with it. Specifically:

```
"field_banner_image":[{
  "target_id":"72",
  "alt":"",
  "title":"",
  "width":"1740",
  "height":"860",
  "url":"http:\/\/dang.dev:8888\/drupal\/sites\/default\/files\/2016-01\/4-ThePiedmont_1740x860_72.jpg"
}]
```

Passing the `target_id` was the ticket!